# Perl DBI: Outputting different table values and saving them

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

My code looks something like this:

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:XYZ:ABC','ABCD', 'XXXX' )
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select "Tablespace" from <TABLE>')
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute
or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

my @schemaname;
my @schematable;
while (@schemaname = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
print "SchemaName is: @schemaname\n";
$schematable[0][0]= $schemaname[0];
$schematable[1][0]= $schemaname[1];
$schematable[2][0]= $schemaname[2];
$schematable[3][0]= $schemaname[3];
$schematable[4][0]= $schemaname[4];

}
warn "Data fetching terminated early by error: $DBI::errstr\n"
if $DBI::err;
print($schematable[0][0]);
print($schematable[1][0]);
print($schematable[2][0]);
print($schematable[3][0]);
print($schematable[4][0]);
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect;
```

What I am trying to do here is output from a SQl database but save it in an array so that I can probably use that data for generating alerts.I keep getting the same string from the last 7 lines. Also when I try the same thing with some other code in the database to save numbers:

```
my $ssth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT STORAGE FROM database")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$dbh->errstr;
$ssth->execute
or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

my @usedschemaspace;
while (@usedschemaspace = $ssth->fetchrow_array( )){
print "Used Schema space: @usedschemaspace\n";
$us= $usedschemaspace[0];
$schematable[0][1]= $schemaname[0];
$schematable[1][1]= $schemaname[1];
$schematable[2][1]= $schemaname[2];
$schematable[3][1]= $schemaname[3];
$schematable[4][1]= $schemaname[4];

}
warn "Data fetching terminated early by error: $DBI::errstr\n"
if $DBI::err;

$ssth->finish();
$sth->finish();
print($schematable[2][1]);
print($schematable[2][2]);
.....
```

#### Disconnect from the database

```
$dbh->disconnect;
```

In both the above cases I do not see anything except the last variable getting stored in schematable[i][j]. Anything evident that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your first you posted, I see two things that really stand out to me:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT "Tablespace" FROM <TABLE>")
```

and

```
while (@schemaname = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
```

You're only requesting a single variable in your SQL query ("Tablespace"), and thus assigning the output of $sth->fetchrow_array() to @schemaname will result in @schemaname only being defined at $schemaname[0].

What exactly does your output look like when you run that first code block?

If you're trying to save all of the returned values into an array, try something like this.

```
my $i=0;
while(my ($schema_name) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $schematable[$i++][0] = $schema_name;
}

#blah blah blah

$i=0;
while(my ($used_schema_space) = $ssth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $schematable[$i++][1] = $used_schema_space;
}
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to print $schematable[2][2] at the end, because you never defined it early on in your script.

I hope this helps...I'm not 100% sure what sort of data structure you're trying to use or what you're aiming to achieve.

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for pointing that out. To answer your question and put things into perspective, I want to output two columns of a  SQL query I mentioned in an array and then generate alerts(emails) based on the stored values.

Comment: Also I was trying to print it just because of testing purposes to see whether the value is captured..